# Open Winword from c# at protected mode

Tags: c#, ms-word

Is there a way to launch WinWord to open a file as [protected mode/view](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/what-is-protected-view-HA010355931.aspx)?

I'm not using Word Automation - just launching the document which causes Winword.exe to start from c#.

Here is the code

```
Process wordProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\\\check.docx");.
```

What do I add to instruct WinWord to not normally open the file but instead show the ProtectedView bar at the top of the document?

Comment: this is protected view: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/what-is-protected-view-HA010355931.aspx

Comment: ms-word has a protected-view feature:http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/what-is-protected-view-HA010355931.aspx. my question is: how can i launch this feature using c# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Word 2010 and up

There exists a Verb in Word 2010 and up called `ViewProtected`.

```
string path = @"c:\path\to\file";
string file = "check.docx";

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(path, file));
psi.Verb = "ViewProtected";
Process wordProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi );
```

Or you can use the commandline option /vp

```
[path to winword.exe]\WinWord.exe  /vp  "c:\path\to\file\check.docx";
```

#### Alternative Option

For earlier versions there are no [commandline arguments](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565) or verbs that let you open a file in protectedmode.

You could use the verb `OpenAsReadOnly` or use a  workaround is to copy the original file and mark it read-only on disk before opening. The following code demonstrates that:

```
string path = @"c:\Your\Path\to\the\file";
string file = "check.docx";
// make copy
string tmp = Path.GetTempFileName().Replace(".tmp", Path.GetExtension(file));
File.Copy(Path.Combine(path,file), tmp );
// make it Read-Only
File.SetAttributes(tmp, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
// Open the copy
Process wordProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tmp );

wordProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

// remove the file as soon as  the process ends
wordProcess.Exited += (o, args) =>
    {
        File.SetAttributes(tmp, FileAttributes.Normal);
        File.Delete(tmp);
    };
```

Comment: Tried it before. but it's not good enough. The user  can edit the file (and he does it), only when he tries to save or to exit- he is getting the read only notification.  the protected-view disables edit from the beginning....

Comment: In Word 2010 and up the verb ViewProtected exist and can be used to open the document in Protected View